# why I am getting different output in iPhone 4s and iPhone 5?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have UITableView where I am displaying list of users. Right now for checking purpose I am displaying user id. Below is the code I am using.

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // new is JSON data of list of users...
    news = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }
    // here in cell I have code to assign data...
    UILabel *myTextLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:9999999999];
    NSLog("id is ===%@===", [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"]);
    myTextLabel.text = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"];

    return cell;
}
```

When I run this in iPhone 4s, I get below output.

```
id is ===4===
id is ===3===
id is ===2===
id is ===1===
```

Now manually from database I delete id 2 and refresh list.

I get output as

```
id is ===4===
id is ===3===
id is ===1===
```

Now I run this in iPhone 5 (with all 4 ids) and get below data....

```
id is ===4===
id is ===3===
id is ===2===
id is ===1===
```

Now I manually delete 2 and reload the list.

```
id is ===4===
id is ===3===
id is ===2===
id is ===1===
```

I still get the above. Still I get 2 in list...

Any reason why I am getting two different output here?

Especially iPhone 5 is giving old output.

---

In iPhone 4 and iPhone 5, I have iOS 6.

I am using stoaryborads, and I am using same stoaryboard for both phones.

---

Code where I am updating data...

```
// everytime I am updating list...
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self getMyData];
}

-(void) getMyData {
    NSLog(@"getMyData...");
    mainTableView.hidden = YES;
    self.indicator.hidden = NO;
    [self.indicator startAnimating];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/xxxx/getBuildingInfoSama.php"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    self.indicator.hidden = NO;
    [self.indicator startAnimating];
    news = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];
    [mainTableView reloadData];
    self.indicator.hidden = YES;
    [self.indicator stopAnimating];
    mainTableView.hidden = NO;
}

- (int) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    int totalNum = news.count;
    NSLog(@"rows to return %d", totalNum);
    return totalNum;
}
```

NSLog says...

```
2013-07-09 18:50:39.127 SAMA[38573:19d03] getMyData...
2013-07-09 18:50:39.131 SAMA[38573:19d03] rows to return 0
2013-07-09 18:50:39.530 SAMA[38573:19d03] didReceiveResponse
2013-07-09 18:50:39.530 SAMA[38573:19d03] didReceiveData
2013-07-09 18:50:39.531 SAMA[38573:19d03] connectionDidFinishLoading
2013-07-09 18:50:39.532 SAMA[38573:19d03] rows to return 4
```

---

### Main Update

When I run same code on one of my friend iPhone 5, its working perfectly. No above problem.

So this means, my app should work in iPhone 5 also.

But question remains, why this is not working in my client iPhone 5?

Any idea?

Comment: What iOS version is on your iPhone 4S and iPhone 5? Did you use different XIB files for Retina 3.5 and Retina 4? And can you show the code you used to delete row from your UITableView?

Comment: @howanghk : I have updated question.. for delete, I have code where I am passing parameter to PHP. Code is not a problem as far I think...

Comment: I think the problem is in your `data`. It might be somehow cached / not updated before you reload your table view after deletion. As long as you're using the same iOS version I think there should be no difference between iPhone 4S and 5. Try `NSLog(@"%@", news);` and see if it contains the old json data.

Comment: @howanghk : Right now don't have iPhone 5. I will check later.. but if news is not getting updated, how can I disable cache in iPhone 5?

Comment: Can you post the code where you are reloading the tableview.  Also after deleting second row and stopping the app and running it again are you still getting all the rows on iPhone 5?

Comment: @Yan : I have updated question with code..

Comment: @howanghk : I have updated the required code.. please check question.. maybe it will help you...

Comment: I guess this is one of those edge cases.  I wonder what if you delete two rows from the the database.  Also try to add an alerview in connectionDidFinishLoading and output news.count and see after you get the new data in your clients iPhone 5 is if it is updated.  Also can you run your clients iPhone 5 connected to your mac and get see the nslog output for easier debugging?

Comment: I just had to ask :)  Have you tried restarting your clients phone and see if the issue persists?

Comment: @FahimParkar you should gather more info, for example: does your client use a caching proxy server? what is the exact iOS version your client is using? (by exact I mean something like 6.1.3 / 6.0.1 etc) and I think you may want to double check your server's response with safari on your client's iphone.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to do

```
news = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  You already have the data loaded in news from before.

You can also try adding cache policy

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:5.0];
```

===
I think the reason you are getting the error `[CFArray respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xa3b4b70` while accessing news is because its not be allocated yet.  The first time the tableview loads the news is nil and when you do objectAtIndex you will get an error.  Try to do alloc init news in viewDidLoad or do lazy loading to make sure new is not nil the first time it's getting accessed, or you can check for being nil before you do objectAtIndex.

Comment: if I don't use `news=...`, I will get error at `[[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"]]`.. this is what I get `*** -[CFArray objectAtIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xa3d90d0`

Comment: Why would news gets deallocated.  Is it a class property?

Comment: @FahimParkar are you using ARC?

Comment: when I print `NSLog(@"setting data.......%@", news);`, I get error as `[CFArray respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xa3b4b70`

Comment: @Yan : Thanks for the answer... I will check on iPhone 5 and get back to you incase of any queries.. I think this will solve the problem...

Comment: @Yan : just curious... in Simulator of Iphone 5 it gives proper list... why the problem is only on iPhone 5?

Comment: @Yan : Maybe I will check answer tomorrow as the person who have iPhone 5 has left for the day... I will get back to you tomorrow incase of anything...

Comment: I am not sure if the setting caching policy will work but worth a try.  It is weird that it only doesn't work on iPhone 5 device.  Also i would still look into why news getting deallocated cellForRowAtIndexPath  I don't think it is good practice to reload the data there.  How do you calculate numberOfRowsInSection Can you post that code too.

Comment: if you are not using ARC, I bet you need to write `[news release]; news = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil] retain];` in `connectionDidFinishLoading`, and remove `news = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as suggested by Yan.

Comment: @howanghk : Thanks for all help.. I can try tomorrow... I have updated question with number of counts...

Comment: @howanghk : I tried your way and code is working.. hope tomorrow it will work on iPhone 5 also... thanks for all help :) :)

Answer (score -1):

1>   Reload table when you are getting data in news array.
  Because table is not reflect data without reloaddata.

2> Delete database file clean build and run it again

Comment: `[mainTableView reloadData];` is doing point 1... if data is added or deleted, do you want to say me to clean and building and run it again???